# Embed Vimeo Player Glitch

Tags: html, css, video, containers, embed

Goal: A clean minimal site which shows a cool video from vimeo, centered on the screen along with a logo and some text.
The site has a background, with a container on top which is centered and which contains all the content.

Problem:
When moving the mouse over the player the whole container disappears:

Link: http://yurapamba.com/

I tried different things with containers and turning parts of the css on and off but nothing seems to do the trick.

Code HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="border">
<div id="content" class="border">
    <div class="logo border2"></div>
    <div class="text border2">
        <div class="wide_space">
        </div>  
            <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/100941286?autoplay=0&amp;color=cf9999&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="740" height="416" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="narrow_space">
            <center><a href="mailto:tijnholwerda1@gmail.com">E-MAIL</a> // <a href="#" target="_blank">PHOTOGALLERY (COMING SOON)</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code CSS

```
#container {
margin: 0 auto; 
padding: 0 20px 0 20px; 
height: auto;
width: 870px;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 0.9;
}

#content {
position:absolute; 
top:50%; 
left: 50%;
height:auto;
width: 760px;
margin:-400px 0 0 -400px;
padding: 35px 20px 50px 20px;
background-color: white;
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
box-shadow:         0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
}
```

Comment: your form.js is html for starters... you have a reference to missing files.. http://jzaefferer.github.io/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js doesnt exist.. EDIT: I see iframes are vimeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the overflow:hidden. I've tidied up your footer too.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 870px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#content {
  position: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: auto;
  width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
}
footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/100941286?autoplay=0&amp;color=cf9999&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="740" height="416" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <footer>
        <a href="mailto:tijnholwerda1@gmail.com">E-MAIL</a> // <a href="#" target="_blank">PHOTOGALLERY (COMING SOON)</a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks close to what i was going for! There's only a weird thin bar at the top of the screen?

Comment: @EmillioMemoso the thin bar was caused by a border:1px solid which I have since removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is a bit strange..

You can remove the absolute positioning on the iframe #content wrapper and remove the strange margins and replace with auto..

```
#content {
height:auto;
width: 760px;
margin:auto;
padding: 35px 20px 50px 20px;
background-color: white;
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
box-shadow:         0px 10px 50px 1px #353535;
}
```

this will get you some better results anyway